# Align icon vertically in dynamic heigh bootstrap col

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an alert in bootstrap which I have an icon as well as some text next to it. Both are broken into `col-md-1` and `col-md-11` respectively. The text on the right side can be dynamic in length so if long it will wrap down to the next line. The icon however will always be the same. I am having trouble figuring out how to keep the icon centered vertically inside of its `col`. By default, if the text is one line, it's centered like so:

[image]

But when the text goes past one line, the icon remains in the same location. I have tried using `vertical-align:middle` on the `<i>` of the icon (fontawesome), but with no results - found here:

[image]

I also tried putting the icon inside of `display:table` to try and take advantage of the `vertical-align:middle` but with no luck. I'd like to keep the Bootstrap column spacing if possible, but I want the icon to be centered no matter the length of the text.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger"
   role="alert">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-2x"
            style="vertical-align:middle;"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            {{vm.modalConfig.message}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT** - Also for ease of help, here's a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/rOV4vsDev3uBTZBJxsK3?p=preview)!

Comment: Post your html/css please.

Comment: please put your code

Comment: Apologies. Posted. I'll put up a plunkr in a sec too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox on `.row` and `align-items: center;` to center vertically.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
  .alert > .row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
</style>
<div class="alert alert-danger"
   role="alert">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-2x"
            style="vertical-align:middle;"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. Ridiculously easy. Is that baked into Bootstrap?

Comment: @erp I'm not sure if Bootstrap has that. Browser support for `flexbox` is GOOD, but not quite universal yet. That's the only reason people still use the relative positioning technique. Also, make sure to include browser support though, especially for `-webkit`, or you might have problems in Safari.

Comment: @erp spent a few minutes reading the bootstrap CSS file (I don't use bootstrap) and looks like it is. Updated my answer.

Comment: @MichaelCoker I found that your previous solution works, but not the updated `align-items-center`

Comment: @erp oh sorry just noticed I'm using bootstrap 4. You're probably using bootstrap 3? With bootstrap 3 you'll have to specify the flex options. It is, however, baked in to bootstrap 4. Reverted my answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use `flexbox` to center them, or use `position: relative` and some `transform` properties.

**Flexbox:**

```
.row {
  -webkit-display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**Relative positioning:**

```
.row {
  position: relative;
}
.row col-md-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate&(-50%);
}
```

Option 1 is definitely the quicker solution. I would also recommmend adding a separate class or ID to `.row` so you don't apply these changes throughout your framework.